# Android Studio & Firebase... Multiple activities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase fully installed into Android Studio, and I've tested it with a couple 1 activity applications, but on the only application with more than one activity, it's not working.

When I try to do the following in my 'Sign up' code:

```
private void makeStudent(String email, String password) {
    Student s = new Student(email, password);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("MYAPP.firebaseio.com/"); 
                                 //took out my app name
    Firebase studentlocation = ref.child("Student");
    studentlocation.setValue(s); //this is the line on which I get the error
    //also, when I go on my firebase site, it hasn't created the Student
    //directory
}
```

The Firebase page said:

> If your Android app has multiple activities, add this code to your Application Class. Otherwise add it in your main activity.

So, I looked around, and this is what I created:
I made a MyApplication.java file, which contained:

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

Then I placed the following into AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Yet, I still receive an error on the exact same line.

How do I fix this Firebase issue? I appreciate any help I can get, please!

ERROR RECEIVED (scroll to the right in the code box):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: professionalgrader.professionalgrader, PID: 3827
                                                                                 com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:347)
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238)
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94)
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16)
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: length=0; index=0 (through reference chain: professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Student["listofTermClasses"])
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2615)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542)
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336)
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: length=0; index=0 (through reference chain: professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Student["listofTermClasses"])
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:184)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:605)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2593)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Student.getListofTermClasses(Student.java:252)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:679)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:534)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142) 
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118) 
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2593) 
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

THE SECOND ERROR:

```
06-15 04:13:34.902 3089-3089/professionalgrader.professionalgrader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: professionalgrader.professionalgrader, PID: 3089
                                                                                 com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:347)
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238)
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94)
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16)
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Class.getGPA()' on a null object reference (through reference chain: professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Student["totalGPA"])
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2615)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542)
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336)
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Class.getGPA()' on a null object reference (through reference chain: professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Student["totalGPA"])
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:184)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:605)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2593)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Class.getGPA()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.Student.getTotalGPA(Student.java:199)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:679)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:534)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142) 
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118) 
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2593) 
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336) 
                                                                                     at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.makeStudent(SignUp.java:94) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp.access$500(SignUp.java:16) 
                                                                                     at professionalgrader.professionalgrader.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:45) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Possible source of error because it told me it couldn't obtain the Snapshot at the line in makeStudent(), but makeStudent() doesn't use Snapshot. Only userExists() does. Note: The variable 'exists' is defined as a static boolean in the SignUp class.

```
    private boolean userExists() {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("MYAPPNAME.firebaseio.com");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Student s = postSnapShot.getValue(Student.class);
                if(s.getEmail().equals(mEmailView.getText().toString())) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            exists = true;
        }
    });
    return exists;
}
```

SOLUTION TO MY ISSUE:
I realized that Snapshot was never used in makeStudent(), and that was where the error started. Thus, I looked in the only place it was used... userExists(), and it turned out that I was correct! The error was produced by trying to identify Student s as a nonexistent student! Thus, I actually needed a try like such:

```
   private boolean userExists() {
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("MYAPPNAME.firebaseio.com");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Student s;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    try {
                        s = postSnapShot.getValue(Student.class);
                        if(s.getEmail().equals(mEmailView.getText().toString())) {
                            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
                            exists = true;
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        exists = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                exists = true;
            }
        });
        return exists;
    }
```

Comment: I would start removing this `/` in `MYAPP.firebaseio.com/`

Comment: Oh yeah, I took out my app name for the purpose of the post, but that's not the issue because my actual code has the proper site name.   - The problem is that I get an error when I do studentlocation.setvalue(s), no matter what I do. Also, the directory that's referenced by studentlocation isn't being created, which makes me think that the FireBase isn't connected to my app.

Comment: Im talking about the slash.

Comment: Oh ok. I tried that now but it didn't work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The application just crashes whenever the line of code is run. Here is the exact error code: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: professionalgrader.professionalgrader, PID: 3827
                                                                                     com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot 'code' I edited the original post to show you more

Comment: What does `Student#getListofTermClasses` do that could cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: It was an unused method (at the time of the error), yet I still commented it out to be sure. It didn't end up working and it gave another error (pasted in original post). Second edit: Do you think that the method userExists() might be the problem? (See last bit of code in original post).

Comment: Never mind! I fixed it! It turned out to be an issue in the userExists() method. I posted the answer in the original post.